# How to refresh a single row in TableViewer instead of single entire table

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Currently i am using TableViewer.On a particular row change, i keep calling `tableViewer.refresh()`. Is there anyway to refresh changed row instead of entire table.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TableViewer.refresh(object)` to refresh just one row. The `object` you specify is the model object that your content provider returns for the row you wish to refresh.

Comment: I have already tried TableViewer.refresh(object) . But no luck .In fact i have tried TableViewer.update() also.I have my code snippet as below ResultModel model = map.get(file);
model.setParam("XYZ");

Comment: refresh(object) definitely works. The object must be the object the content provider returns for the row. Calling `setUseHashlookup(true)` on the view might help. Edit your question and provide a [mcve]